# Stop master volume from setting all other active channels’ volume to 100

Tags: sound, alsa, volume-control

1. Run `alsamixer`
2. Change volume levels for a channel that is not *Master* (*PCM* or *Front* for example)
3. Change system volume (via GUI for example)

Now, the master volume will change, **but the volume of all other unmuted channels will be set to 100, too**.

How can I stop this? Is this a bug? Because if it is not, what’s the purpose of setting anything in the `alsamixer` UI apart from the *Auto-Mute* setting?

I’m running Ubuntu 18.04.